# Getting error while establishing connection between android and mysql using PhP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am creating a app which will show the data of MySQL table in the card_layout of the android app.

The below mentioned is the connection code in MainActivity.java

```
private void load_data_from_server(final int id) {
    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://10.10.2.2/develop/php_recyler_demo.php?id="+id).build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());

                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    MyData data = new MyData(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("description"),object.getString("image"));
                    data_list.add(data);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    task.execute(id);
}
```

For the MySQL connection I am using PhP and executing in the `XAMPP` server as `localhost`, the code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    //$id = $_GET["id"];
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

    $query = "select * from recyclerdb where id between ($id+1) and ($id+4)";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        # code...
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    header('Content-type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

My table structure is as follows:
[image: The table structure]

When I run this PhP file using browser then I am getting correct output as `JSON array`:[image: Image for the output of PhP file in browser]

But if I execute my app in android studio using emulator

I am getting `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

The problem I am getting at the two lines of `MainActivity.java`:

`AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>()`

`Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();`

I did research for a long time, please someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` means you just cannot connect to desired server.

I guess for emulator you have to replace

```
http://10.10.2.2/
```

to

```
localhost/
```

Comment: If I replace localhost then I get `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. In my opinion if I use localhost then emulator will find the address in itself, isn't it?

Comment: @Shambhu not necessary. Try 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: But by adding `localhost` I got `connection refused`. What should I do now?

Comment: After adding the `127.0.0.1` I got `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80'.

Comment: @Shambhu a few stupid questions: 1) Emulator on same computer as XAMPP? Does 127.0.0.1 opens your script in browser? From where did you took http://10.10.2.2/ address?

Comment: Q1.-> Yes, Q2-> Yes. Q3-> I was browsing the solution and I got the statement, that for the emulator I've to use the private IP as `10.10..2.2`